# Python Graphs: Latex Math rendering of node labels

Tags: python, latex, networkx, pygraphviz

I am using the following code to create a `pygraphviz` graph. But is it possible to make it render latex math equations (see Figure 1)?  If not, is there an alternative python library that plots similar graphs but supports latex rendering ?

```
import networkx as nx

from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import to_agraph

G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(1,color='blue',style='filled',
             fillcolor='white',shape='square', label="$3x+2$")
G.add_node(2)
G.add_node(3)
G.add_edge(1, 2)
G.add_edge(1, 3)
G.add_edge(3, 4)

A = to_agraph(G)
A.layout('dot')
A.draw('test1.png')
```

This results in the following figure

[image: Figure 1]

Figure 1

Comment: I don't see any reference to LaTeX in the [PyGraphviz documentation](https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/development/). Is there a reason you think this should work?

Comment: I see! I edited the question to make the request not restricted to pyGraphviz. In other words, is there a python library that can plot similar graphs with Latex rendering ? I know matplotlib renders latex, but it's not good with such graphs.

Comment: Did you managed in the end ?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe https://dot2tex.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ will work for you?
Try

```
import dot2tex
texcode = dot2tex.dot2tex(A.to_string(), format='tikz', crop=True)
```

Comment: doesn't work, $3x+2$ still remains as $3x+2$, but thanks for trying!

Comment: The point of dot2tex is to render tex expressions. There are some examples here http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/graphics/dot2tex/dot2tex.pdf.  You can probably make it work if you spend a little effort.

Comment: Note texlbl= not label=...