# Latex equation in Graphviz digraph in Python Sphinx doc

Tags: python, latex, python-sphinx, graphviz, dot2tex

I want to create a sphinx doc with a Graphviz graph that has a node with LaTeX equation.

I tried:

```py
r"""
.. graphviz::

   digraph foo {
      a_1 [label="$x_{0}$"];
      a_1 -> "baz";
   }
"""
```

But the label in the resulting graph is `$x_{0}$` instead of *x*<sub>0</sub>.

The extensions specified in the `conf.py` of the Sphinx doc are:

```py
extensions = ["sphinx.ext.autodoc", "sphinx.ext.napoleon",
              "sphinx.ext.mathjax", "sphinx.ext.graphviz"]
```

Related:

[Improve positioning of subscript and superscript on node labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334738/improve-positioning-of-subscript-and-superscript-on-node-labels)

dot2tex [Python Graphs: Latex Math rendering of node labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35830447/python-graphs-latex-math-rendering-of-node-labels)